# How to avoid eval() when looping through array?

Tags: javascript

I am working with Greensock animation library and when building a sequential animation (where one thing ends and the next starts right away) you have to enter it like this:

```
childTL.to($box, 1, {x:50,y:0})
       .to($box, 1, {x:50,y:50})
       .to($box, 1, {x:-50,y:50})
       .to($box, 1, {x:-50,y:0});
```

The issue I have is that I am storing all the things in a database or as variables and so need to build things incrementally using for loops.

What I want is something like this:

```
var animation = {
  "name": "movearound",
  "sequence": [{
    "duration": "1",
    "vars": {
      "x": "50",
      "y": "0"
    }
  }, {
    "duration": "1",
    "vars": {
      "x": "50",
      "y": "0"
    }
  }, {
    "duration": "1",
    "vars": {
      "x": "50",
      "y": "0"
    }
  }, {
    "duration": "1",
    "vars": {
      "x": "50",
      "y": "0"
    }
  }]
}
target = $(".target123")
childTL = new TimelineLite{onUpdate: updateSlider});

for (S = 0; S < animatelayers.sequence.length; S++) {
  duration = animatelayers.sequence[S]["duration"];
  sequence = animatelayers.sequence[S]["vars"];
  if (S == 0) {

    childTL.to(target, duration, sequence)
  } else {
    .to(".target", duration, sequence);
  }
}
```

I know I could do it with concatenating strings together and then do an eval() on it, but is there a way to do it without?

Edit for why I am talking about eval():

I guess the trouble I have is how picky Greensock is when it comes to things coming in as strings vs objects - for example you can use `$("#target")` in the .to(), but you can't use it if you define it as a variable first `var target = $("#target");` and then `childTL.to(target, 1, {x:50,y:0})` would fail, but if you do it as `var target = "#target"` it would work. So in the past I had created it all exactly like Greensock wanted as a string, and then used eval(). While I can keep doing that, I prefer to look for better ways of accomplishing things.

Comment: It's not at all clear what your problem is. What would the `eval()` you don't want to do look like?

Comment: It's not clear from your question why you think you need to use `eval()` at all, nor why you think you need to use string concatenation.  Perhaps if you show the data you're starting with that needs to be transformed into your desired object?

Comment: `target` is unused. What are `animatelayers`, `duration`, and `sequence`? What is `childTL[S]`?

Comment: Sorry for those oversights, I oversimpified the code and left some things out when trying to make it easy to read. I tuned it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code makes no sense, so instead I'm going to demonstrate how to convert your original snippet to use a data structure and a loop:

```
childTL.to($box, 1, {x:50,y:0})
       .to($box, 1, {x:50,y:50})
       .to($box, 1, {x:-50,y:50})
       .to($box, 1, {x:-50,y:0});
```

First we define our data:

```
var coords = [
    {x: 50, y: 0},
    {x: 50, y:50},
    {x:-50, y:50},
    {x:-50, y: 0}
];
```

Then we loop:

```
var obj = childTL;
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    obj = obj.to($box, 1, coords[i]);
}
```

This is a strict conversion of the original chained `.to(...).to(...).to(...)` calls. However, doing things this way isn't actually necessary. The `.to` method simply returns the object for convenience (according to https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/Animation/TimelineLite/to/); you don't have to use it.

You can simply say:

```
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    childTL.to($box, 1, coords[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 for separating data from logic. Why not use a `forEach` loop? it's cleaner, no mutation and leave no trace (the `i` variable)

Comment: @goldylucks `.forEach` has a number of disadvantages: The syntax is super clunky (at least without `=>`); it's not a real loop (you can't use `break` or `continue`); last time I looked it was slower than `for`; it's more annoying to debug / step through.

Comment: `continue` is like `return`. it's true there's no `break`, tho in the vast majority of the cases this is not used (at least from my experience). about the syntax, I guess different strokes for different folks ;) tho from what I see it looks like the community is going towards `forEach` and `map` over the old for loops.

Comment: Tanks Melpomene, if I do the second example, I end up with an issue like this one: http://codepen.io/ajhalls/pen/NdMOPr?editors=1111 where the last one out over writes all previous ones, I need to think about the previous one.  I have tried to restructure all the animatecss to greensock here: http://codepen.io/ajhalls/pen/JdWzML and am looking at how to better structure the data for more flexibility for a GUI timeline tool.

Comment: @Alan Why are you creating multiple `TimelineLite` instances? I would have expected something like: `var tl = new TimelineLite; for (...) { tl.to(".target", duration, sequence); }`

Comment: I put together a WYSIWYG timeline editing tool here: https://ajhalls.github.io/Simple-Animation-Timeline-for-Greensock/ which lets you create multiple timelines with multiple start points, the trouble is that it currently doesn't let you daisy chain commands together the way I have things arranged. I am now integrating that into my larger project which will allow multiple targets, with multiple timelines.